# Can we create a potential difference across the ends of a metallic rod just by accelerating it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, charge

If we take a metallic rod and accelerate it then what would happen?

My view is that, as a metal has a sea of free electrons flowing about these free electrons will experience a pseudo force and will somewhat get displaced. This can create a Potential Difference in the rod as the positively charged kernels are fixed in the metallic lattice and hence they wont get displaced.
So a net displacement of negative charge and hence a Potential difference across the ends of the rod?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Try looking at this paper (it is behind a pay wall so I can't access it): 
Gravitation-Induced Electric Field near a Metal by  L. I. Schiff and M. V. Barnhill
Phys. Rev. 151, 1067 – Published 25 November 1966                                                         It seems to suggest that there will be an electric field generated by a conductor placed in an gravitional field. Apparentley it is called the Schiff Barnhill effect.

Answer (score 1):

No. They are already accelerating. What potential difference does is make electrons go in a particular direction,  which your external force cant. Even if all electrons does experience a pseudo force  their relative motion won't change between each electron.